# Tracking progress of upload of Parse object

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm looking for a way to track the upload progress of a `PFObject`, similar to the one that works on the `PFFile` - `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:progressBlock:`. Unfortunately, this method with periodic callbacks does not exist in other save methods, and **I want to be able to create this effect in the cloud code**.

Basically, in my client code, I would call a cloud function, passing in some info. The cloud function would execute whatever it needs to do; Many different objects are created/saved in succession, and finally, sends a response.

I want to make my cloud code imitate the `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:progressBlock:` method, so I can display the progress to the user. How can I accomplished that?

Comment: You could use `NSURL:connection:didReceiveData:` client side

Comment: Not doable as a practical matter.  Alternatives are: 1) heuristic on the client, estimating the delay and fake progress with a timer, 2) break those server operations into separate requests from the client and update progress as each completes.  But otherwise not doable, short of building your own server.